# Estimate for integral with integrand $e^{(\log t)^{\alpha}}$.

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $\alpha>1$. Is there an estimate for large $r$ (where large means that there is $r_{0}>0$ such that for all $r\geq r_{0}$ the estimate holds) for the following (positive) function $$\Phi(r)=\int_{1}^{r}{e^{(\log t)^{\alpha}}dt},$$ in the form that there is a (positive) function $\Psi(r)$ such that $$\Psi(r)\simeq \Phi(r),$$ where $"\simeq"$ means that there are constants $c_{1}, c_{2}>0$ such that $$c_{1}\leq\frac{\Psi(r)}{\Phi(r)}\leq c_{2}.$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok how about:
$$x=\log(t)\Rightarrow dt=tdx=e^xdx$$
and so:
$$e^{(\log t)^\alpha}dt=e^{x^\alpha}e^xdx$$
and your integral becomes:
$$\Phi(r)=\int_0^{\ln(r)}e^{x^\alpha}e^xdx$$
$$e^{x^\alpha}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{\alpha k}}{k!}$$
$$\Phi(r)=\int_0^{\ln r}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{\alpha k}e^x}{k!}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\int_0^{\ln r}x^{ak}e^xdx$$
$$u=-x\Rightarrow dx=-du$$
$$\Phi(r)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\alpha k+1}}{k!}\int_0^{\ln(1/r)}u^{\alpha k}e^{-u}du$$
Which can be expressed in terms of a sum of the incomplete gamma function.